# How to Print a Preset Report in Codeigniter and save as PDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have made an application in codeigniter can anyone tell me any library or Helper class or another thing outside codeigniter that i can use to put values coming from database in a preset report and take it out as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try codeignitor download helper. You will get the solution.

here is the simple example for the download helper.

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = "Your data"; 
force_download("PDF_filename.pdf", $data);
```